# Crime reported right after Paying a Social Call is marked as done

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Red Dead Redemption 2, I just played the chapter 2 mission Paying a Social Call. When I finished it, right after grabbing the money from the chimney and then opening the locked box inside, I got a wanted status, getting the message “crime reported.”

What is up? This happened once, so I re-did the mission, thinking I messed up. It happened again, this time a little bit after leaving the cabin.

**What’s going on? Is this supposed to happen, or am I doing something wrong?** Is my game glitching?

Answer (score 2):

Like many missions will do, this is one of the missions that will give you a wanted status after finishing the mission. The idea is that you have to escape getting caught after finishing it.

**It's not a bounty you can pay off.** You have to escape the lawmen that come after you after the mission. Note that the mission is completed regardless.